# Is this record normal Thread-90122 in WAS7 Systemout.log?

Tags: logging, out-of-memory, websphere

I'm facing with OutOfMemory error on WAS 7.0.0.41. Could you kindly review the SystemOut.log, please.
(my log4j logger prints the Thread name too)

Is it **Thread-65799** ok? This count grows up to about 100000.
Thanks!

```
[9/28/17 11:33:18:526 YEKT] 000008b9 SystemOut     O 2017-09-28 11:33:18,526 [Thread-65799] INFO  Filenet:716 - ceConnection:  Class=com.filenet.apiimpl.core.ConnectionImpl URI=iiop://fnce.server.ru:2809/FileNet/Engine Parameters={}
[9/28/17 11:33:18:526 YEKT] 000008b9 SystemOut     O 2017-09-28 11:33:18,526 [Thread-65799] INFO  Filenet:720 - Factory.Domain.fetchInstance()...
[9/28/17 11:33:18:542 YEKT] 000008b9 SystemOut     O 2017-09-28 11:33:18,542 [Thread-65799] INFO  Filenet:723 - Domain: dom1
[9/28/17 11:33:18:557 YEKT] 000008b9 SystemOut     O 2017-09-28 11:33:18,557 [Thread-65799] INFO  Filenet:750 - objectStore: OS1
[9/28/17 11:33:18:557 YEKT] 000008b9 SystemOut     O 2017-09-28 11:33:18,557 [Thread-65799] INFO  Filenet:751 - connected.
[9/28/17 11:33:18:557 YEKT] 00000478 SystemOut     O CvLFU3tWA_RK8XCqPGoQFyU
[9/28/17 11:33:18:573 YEKT] 00000478 SystemOut     O CvLFU3tWA_RK8XCqPGoQFyU
[9/28/17 11:33:18:682 YEKT] 00000478 SystemOut     O 2017-09-28 11:33:18,682 [WebContainer : 39] INFO  ViewWindows:2460 - viewsPDF()
[9/28/17 11:33:18:682 YEKT] 00000478 SystemOut     O 2017-09-28 11:33:18,682 [WebContainer : 39] INFO  ViewWindows:2561 - final ct: application/pdf
[9/28/17 11:33:18:682 YEKT] 00000478 SystemOut     O 2017-09-28 11:33:18,682 [WebContainer : 39] INFO  ViewWindows:2192 - isLimitedVersion: false
[9/28/17 11:33:19:634 YEKT] 0000036b SystemOut     O 2017-09-28 11:33:19,634 [WebContainer : 26] INFO  WorkplaceApplication:451 - Login thread get result! Start App
[9/28/17 11:33:19:634 YEKT] 0000036b SystemOut     O 2017-09-28 11:33:19,634 [WebContainer : 26] INFO  WorkplaceApplication:467 - Filenet Login success!
[9/28/17 11:33:19:649 YEKT] 0000036b SystemOut     O 2017-09-28 11:33:19,649 [WebContainer : 26] INFO  Filenet:1106 - ReadConfiguartion()
[9/28/17 11:33:19:649 YEKT] 0000036b SystemOut     O 2017-09-28 11:33:19,649 [WebContainer : 26] INFO  Filenet:1127 - Read config about 380 document types!
[9/28/17 11:33:19:665 YEKT] 0000036b SystemOut     O 2017-09-28 11:33:19,665 [WebContainer : 26] INFO  Filenet:1166 - ==========================
[9/28/17 11:33:19:665 YEKT] 0000036b SystemOut     O 2017-09-28 11:33:19,665 [WebContainer : 26] INFO  Filenet:1168 - SEA_PodrCode
[9/28/17 11:33:19:665 YEKT] 0000036b SystemOut     O 2017-09-28 11:33:19,665 [WebContainer : 26] INFO  Filenet:1168 - SEA_accounting_group
[9/28/17 11:33:19:665 YEKT] 0000036b SystemOut     O 2017-09-28 11:33:19,665 [WebContainer : 26] INFO  Filenet:1168 - SEA_DocumentType
```

Comment: Do the threads go away, or are there actually 100k threads in play by the time it runs out of memory?  Also, do you know what is creating all those Thread objects?  The name implies that it's not the server - server-managed threads will generally have a name like the "WebContainer" threads in the lower half of that log snippet - "<poolname> : <index>".  "Thread-<index>" is the default thread name assigned by the JVM.

Comment: After server restart 'Threads' records appears in the SystemOut.log and start with "Thread-1", "Thread-2" etc.   Yes, I guess. There is a couple of code, running Thread. I will try to remove them.

Comment: Jarid, does **Thread-65799** mean all that 65799 threads in memory?

Comment: I believe it means that it was the 65799th thread created by the JVM, including threads that have started and died.  You can tell how many are in memory by forcing a thread dump (if you're on a *nix platform, "kill -3" against the PID) - that will list all threads currently running in the JVM.